# Array elements overwrite each other when adding others

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I want to make a Pet Shop/Store game in Java and in this game you can create multiple dogs. When you enter "doginfo" the program will show all of your dogs' information. (that's the "goal")

I've tried to make an array of 1000 Mammal elements and add, every time you create a dog, an element corresponding to that dog's information.

Parts of `class PetShop`:

```
public static int count = 0;

if(cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("dogInfo"))
{
    Mammal.dogInfo();
}

private static void createDog() 
{       

    System.out.print("Select the name of your dog: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Select the colour of your dog: ");
    String colour = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Select the maximum height of your dog (cm): ");
    double maxHeight = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Select the gender of your dog (0 - female, 1 - male): ");
    int intGender = scan.nextInt();
    boolean male;

    if(intGender == 0)
    {
        male = false;
        err = false;
    }
    else if(intGender == 1)
    {
        male = true;
        err = false;
    }
    else
    {
        male = false;
        err = true;
    }

    if (err == false)
    {
        Mammal.mArray[count] = new Mammal(name, colour, maxHeight, male);
        count++;        
        System.out.println("A new dog was created!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Select between 0 and 1!");
        return;
    }
}
```

Parts of `class Mammal`:

```
public static Mammal[] mArray = new Mammal[1000];

private static String name,colour;
private static double height,maxHeight;
private static int health;
private static boolean male;

//constructor
public Mammal(String n, String c, double mH, boolean m)
{
    name = n;
    colour = c;
    height = 9;
    maxHeight = mH;
    health = 100;
    male = m;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("Name: %s, Colour: %s, Age: %d, Health: %d, Height: %.2f, Maximum Height: %.2f, Gender: %s"
                ,name, colour, age, health, height, maxHeight, male ? "Male" : "Female"
        );
}

public static void dogInfo()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length; i++) {
        if (mArray[i] != null)
        {
            System.out.println(mArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if it's too much code ^-^.

If I enter for the first dog name steve, colour brown, maxHeight 60, male 1 and for the second dog name danielle, colour white, maxHeight 45, male 0 then, when I type "doginfo" I'd expect

```
Name: steve, Colour: brown, Age: 0, Health: 100, Height: 9,00, Maximum Height: 60,00, Gender: Male
Name: danielle, Colour: white, Age: 0, Health: 100, Height: 9,00, Maximum Height: 45,00, Gender: Female
```

but the actual output is

```
Name: danielle, Colour: white, Age: 0, Health: 100, Height: 9,00, Maximum Height: 45,00, Gender: Female
Name: danielle, Colour: white, Age: 0, Health: 100, Height: 9,00, Maximum Height: 45,00, Gender: Female
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Where did you declare your `Scanner ` class?

Comment: Please, come up with [mcve] cause it is not clear how your code suppose to work.

Comment: Hint: dont put an array of class X into class X. A Mammal class represents one Mammal, so putting an array of Mammals into that class doesnt make sense. An egg doesnt contain a box for eggs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When declaring a variable as [static](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java), changing it will make it change for every instance of your class.

To avoid this behaviour, don't declare them as static and refer to the variable other than where you declared it as

```
this.variableName
```

instead of

```
variableName
```

so that your program accesses the objects variables you called the function on and not some other global variable.

Comment: And, how did it go?

Comment: And, if you are from Switzerland, as I can see in your profile, `Danke schön und gute Nacht!`